Github, How to copy file from a brach to a folder in main
I have two branches, main and dev. I want to copy all files from the dev branch and put them into a folder within the main branch. How can I do this?
I tried the following steps: checking out main, running git add and git commit, and then performing a git merge. However, nothing happened. Any suggestions?

Not sure it's a good practice to put all the content of a dev branch in the main. Normally two branches are paralelle and with the same structure, so you can merge them once the dev branch is stable. On branch will never be in a subfolder of another. However, you can create a second repo and use submodules https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Try this:
Check out the main branch:
git checkout main

Create a new folder to hold the dev files:
mkdir dev_files

Check out the files from the dev branch into this new folder:
git checkout dev -- .
mv * dev_files/

Add the new folder and commit the changes:
git add dev_files
git commit -m "Copied files from dev branch into dev_files folder"

and finally push the changes to the remote repository (if that is needed):
git push origin main

Hope that helps :)
